# Why isn't the spark-submit command providing any output on a Python script?

Tags: pyspark

spark-submit didn't provide any output.

I have tried he below command to submit a spark job:

```
spark-submit C:\Users\HP\Documents\PythonScripts\spark_practice.py
```

Attached the result in the form of screenshot for your reference.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you shouldn't expect an output in the console, but it depends on your sink in the script, which could be dumping the results in a file, so check your logic

For the attached error, it says it can't find the python file, so try to add `file:///` in front of the path to indicate that this is a local file

```bash
$ spark-submit file:///C:/Users/HP/Documents/PythonScripts/spark_practice.py
```